# Git keeps adding files to repository than should be ignored

Tags: git, android-studio, gitignore

I'm working in Android Studio and I don't know if this problem is related to Android Studio or `git`:

I want to keep the `.iml` files that are created by Android Studio out of my `git` repository so I put them in a `gitignore` file which you can see in the screenshot, but the files keep getting added. 
I tried to remove them with

```
git rm --cached
```

which seems to work for a while but then they keep getting added. 
Is it a problem that I have one gitignore file in the project folder and one in the module folder?

PS: The screenshot shows the `gitignore` file in the project folder, and the `gitignore` plugin recognized the `Adjust.iml` file so I'm confident the entry for `Adjust.iml` ist in the right file.

EDIT: The root folder of the project is:

```
C:\Projekte\iw-android
```

the gitignore file shown in the screenshot is:

```
C:\Projekte\iw-android\.gitignore
```

The file to be ignore is

```
C:\Projekte\iw-android\Adjust\Adjust.iml
```

and the entry in the `gitignore` file is:

```
Adjust/Adjust.iml
```

I tried manually entering it or with rightclick -> add to gitignore in Android Studio, same result and it looks correct to me.

[image]

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks! Uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: Is it in a directory, or in the root of the project? Looks like `.gitignore` and your file aren't in the same directory.

Comment: See my edit for the paths.

Comment: did you commit the newly edited gitignore file ? 

As you said you removed the file once using git rm --cached and then it worked for a while and then after that it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to ignore all `.iml` files then a `*.iml` pattern in your `.gitignore` should suffice. You'll obviously have to remove any currently tracked `.iml` files before the pattern takes effect on them.

Take a look at the [`gitignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) documentation for details.

Comment: Ill try that, thanks. Is git rm --cached the correct command for removing those files from being tracked?

Comment: @Ascorbin yes, followed by a `git commit`.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, this didn't help either.

Comment: @Ascorbin I've tested this locally and it works perfectly fine. Your problem must lie elsewhere then and we can only speculate. Based in the information you gave us it's not possible to determine the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to remove them with git rm --cached which seems to work for a while

So that probably means you did not commit your `.gitignore` file into the repository.